# Nginx service failing randomly: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: 20.04, systemd, services, nginx

I've been experiencing that the Nginx service is failing at random times, and I'm unsure why.

`syslog` gives me the following, when doing a `cat syslog | grep`:

```
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 23 00:00:06 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 logrotate[1506419]: Job for nginx.service failed.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 logrotate[1506419]: See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 logrotate[1506425]: Job for nginx.service failed.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 logrotate[1506425]: See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 logrotate[1506430]: Job for nginx.service failed.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 logrotate[1506430]: See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 23 00:00:07 serv4 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

`nginx -t` gives me the following:

```bsh
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```